# Почему нет звука после компиляции Pygame через Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter, pygame, pyinstaller

Всем доброго времени суток!
Пишу игру на Python, используя tkinter. Добавил фоновую музыку и звуки.
Музыку в фоне играет Pygame (Thread воспроизводит в отдельном потоке), а звуки Playsound.
При работе самого py файла проблем никаких нету.
Компилирую в exe при помощи Pyinstaller. Сначала вылезла ошибка pywin32. Установил.
Теперь ошибки нету, но в игре все равно нету музыки.
Вторая библиотека, которая воспроизводит звуки работает корректно.
Проблема либо в Pygame, либо в Thread.
При этом Thread используется еще для счета секунд и они корректно считаются.
Кто может помочь с этим?

Библиотека Pygame:

```
from pygame import mixer

stop = False
volume = 1
def play(stop, volume):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
    mixer.music.load('Data\\Music\\music.mp3')
    mixer.music.play(-1)
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        if stop == True:
            mixer.music.pause()
            break

# Вызов выполнения функции в фоне
x = threading.Thread(target=play, args=(stop, volume), daemon=True)
x.start()
```

Библотека Playsound:

```
from playsound import *
def grass():
    playsound('Data\\Music\\grass.mp3')
```

Upd: Скомпилил только что вместе с консолью и выдало вот такую ошибку:
[image: :]

Answer (score 1):

Решение: Я конвертировал mp3 файл в wav и у меня нормально работает exe.